# Generate Random Number With Defined Data Type

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate a really long integer random number, I want it to be 224 bits random number. But the longest data type I can find is unsigned long long which is 64 bits. First I did this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "random.h"
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    unsigned long long num1 = rand();
    unsigned long long num2 = rand();

    cout<<"1st random number = " << num1 << endl;
    cout<<"2nd random number = " << num2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My idea would be to define new data type that is 224 bit integer.
So that I tried make new random.h file :

```
class int224 
{
    unsigned int data[7];
}
```

And then modified the first code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "random.h"
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int224 num1 = rand();
    int224 num2 = rand();

    cout<<"1st random number = " << num1 << endl;
    cout<<"2nd random number = " << num2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it returned errors, maybe I made a mistake when I defined the new data type, I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: "..  it returned errors .." Please list them.

Comment: Even `unsigned long long num1 = rand();` won't actually give you a 64-bit random number. It will be limited to however many bits `rand()` returns, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with following, not sure if this will work for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

struct int224 
{
    unsigned int data[7];

    int224 operator+(int224);
    int224 operator-(int224);

    int224 ()
    {
     unsigned seed =
         std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

        std::minstd_rand0 mygen (seed); 

      for(auto i=0;i<7;i++)
        data[i]=mygen();    
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const int224&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int224& r)
{
    for(auto i=0;i<7;i++)
        os<<r.data[i];
    return os;
}

int main ()
{

  int224 r;
  std::cout<<r<<std::endl;

  int224 j;
  std::cout<<j;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @POW I tried this, and the error is :

This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options

Comment: @dulipat C++0X, is an experimental standard. Official named as C++11, but the implementation is incomplete in GCC. You can enable it by passing `--std=c++0x` to compiler. Check status page: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html before complaining that something is broken/not working.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a function that generate random `int224` and the compiler don't know that class.

you can create your own `Rand()` function in the `int224` and use that. the function will put random number in each of the array's cells

Answer (score 1):

It can not work like that. The built-in rand function returns an `int` and you can not make it return something bigger by just assigning the result to a bigger value. You will have to implement a more complex logic and use a few calls to `rand` to initialize different consequent bits in the result.

Answer (score 1):

As you have an array of 7 defined in the class, you will have to call the rand function 7 time to initialize each element.

Also if you want your numbers to be unsigned then it is fine but if you want them to be signed then take care that while accessing the numbers, you cast the first 6 as unsigned and the last one as signed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you, what do you mean by "call the rand function 7 time to initialize each element" ? How and where to call the rand function?
Yes, I want the numbers to be unsigned.

Comment: loop 7 times to assign each element of array data[7]. and do keep in ming the second point in my answer. as it may create a problem if you try to append the numbers in a string or so.